# Understanding of formula for arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

A arithmetic progression is defined by:

$$\begin{cases}
a_1=a_1 \\
a_n= a_{n-1}+d
\end{cases}
$$

I can't understand this passage from a algebra book about arithmetic progression.
The formula is $$S=\frac{(a_r+a_s)+(r-s+1)}{2}$$
and it's the formula used to find the sum of all the terms in a arithmetic progression from $a_r$ to $a_s$ and here is the demonstration:

$$a_r+a_s=(a_{r+1}-d)+(a_{s-1}+d)=a_{r+1}+a_{s-1}\ \text{and so}$$
$$2S=2(a_r+a_{r+1}+a_{r+2}+\cdots+a_{s-2}+a_{s-1}+a_{s})=$$
$$= (a_r+a_{s})+(a_{r+1}+a_{s-1})+\cdots +(a_{s-1}+a_{r+1})+(a_{s}+a_{r})=$$
Now here's the passage I don't understand; from the last formula:
$$S=\frac{(a_{r}+a_{s})(r-s+1)}2$$

Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
\begin{align*}
2S & =
(a_r+a_{s})+(a_{r+1}+a_{s-1})+\cdots +(a_{s-1}+a_{r+1})+(a_{s}+a_{r}) \cr
 & = (a_r+a_s)+(a_r+a_s)+\cdots + (a_r+a_s) + (a_r+a_s) \cr
 & = (r-s+1)(a_r+a_s).
\end{align*}

by using $a_r+a_s=a_{r+1}+a_{s-1}$ from above successively.